# Extract wallpapers from macOS installation CDs or disk images without installation

Tags: macos, wallpaper

Is there a way to extract wallpapers from macOS installation CD without performing installation itself?

Yes, I understand 7zip can unzip dmg file as a simple archive. But what next? I don't see any wallpapers after unzipping.

My ultimate aim is to get the original unaltered desktop background pictures included with Mac OS X versions 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit this answer may be a little presumptuous of me.

Assuming I'm reading between the lines correctly, if all you're wanting to do is grab a copy of the macOS desktop background image from an earlier version of macOS, these are readily available from many websites.

For example, you can download 5K versions of these images at [Every Default macOS Wallpaper – in Glorious 5K Resolution](https://512pixels.net/projects/default-mac-wallpapers-in-5k/).

**NOTE:** I am not affiliated in any way with the website above.

---

**[UPDATE}**

After discussion with the OP it was established that what they were after were all the *original* desktop background pictures from Mac OS X versions 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9.

On the off chance anyone else will want/need these, I have uploaded a [.zip file](https://ufile.io/ih299) containing all of these in their original unaltered state. After clicking on the link just click on the button representing the download option you want (slow v turbo).

**NOTE:** The file was uploaded to uploadfiles.io at the request of the OP. I have no affiliation with this service.

Comment: Thanks :-) Yes, I know about such websites. The problem is that wallpapers hosted on them are oftenly _modified_. I don't _why_ these people think it will be a good idea to manually resize 3200 x 2000 into 5120 x 2880 or _why_ it will be a good idea to change the exposure (brightness).

Comment: Ah ok, I’m surprised people would change the exposure, although I’m not surprised they may want to resize the images. Screen resolutions have changed significantly over the years and some earlier macOS wallpapers just don’t look good as wallpapers anymore on some displays. Of course, that’s assuming you wanted to use it as a wallpaper on a hi res display to begin with. So, getting back to your question, was their a particular macOS desktop background you were after? Or are you wanting to extract these from multiple versions of macOS?

Comment: Different backgrounds from different Mac OS (OS X, macOS, etc) versions. I want to create a collection of genuine ones :-)

Comment: Also, another problem is JPEG-compression. The same background hosted on 2 different sites sometimes has completely different file size: for example 15 MB on first site and 10 MB on the second, with the same dimensions (5120 x 2880).

Comment: Ok, the *issue* I have with this is that your question is rather broad. Not all versions of macOS were distributed via optical media. Also, when you say you're after a collection of *backgrounds from different Mac OS (OS X, macOS, etc) versions*, how far back are you trying to go? Just back to Mac OS X 10.0, or even further back to the Classic Mac OS days? Better still, which ones are you missing? I'm not trying to be difficult, it's just that I think the answer to extracting wallpapers from macOS installation CDs will differ depending on the version of macOS we're talking about.

Comment: *How far back are you trying to go?* - Well, I would say, the backgrounds which were provided from Tiger (10.4) to Mavericks (10.9). I don't like Yosemite's backgrounds and later ones. *Better still, which ones are you missing?* - I bought my first Mac from another person (he bought him another one, with better configuration). It was installed Yosemite with custom background and all default backgrounds were removed. So, I missing *everything* from 10.4 to 10.9 :-)

Comment: Okay, well, I may be able to help you with those. I'll have to check. Are you only after the *default* desktop background for each, or all of the ones that were bundled with each? Although I know that wouldn't answer your question *per se*! LOL

Comment: *Are you only after the default desktop background for each, or all of the ones that were bundled with each?* - All of the ones. *Although I know that wouldn't answer your question per se! LOL* - Yes, but it would be even better then answering it :-) It is my 1st question here and I'm very surprised to see so friendly atmosphere, really :-)

Comment: Haha, took me a little time (had to boot up six machines, which also meant connecting and disconnecting a keyboard, mouse and monitor for all of them) but it was fun seeing some of these old babies come back to life (I have an old 15" PowerBook G4 that booted up fine which I remembered *not* working, go figure!) Anyway, I've copied all of the *Desktop Pictures* folders for the respective versions of macOS into a single folder and have zipped them (705.8 MB). Obviously there's a lot of duplicates in that. Now, do you have a preference as to how I *transfer* this to you?

Comment: Fantastic! Probably [UploadFiles](https://uploadfiles.io/) will be a good way for transferring? It doesn't require any registration and could handle files up to 5 GB :-)

Comment: Okay, it took a few attempts to get it uploaded, but it all seems good now. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Wow, amazing! :-) Yeah, there are really original images, neatly divided into original directories! Thank you very much! :-) **For further readers:** the link will be available for 4 weeks. After this time, if you still need it, leave a *temporary* comment under my question - and I will reupload it somewhere.